# Error While installing FOSREST Bundle Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to install "FOSREST" Bundle to create restful web services for Ionic Framework so that I can run my services that will be in Symfony2.3.7 to run on a ionic framework like angular.js etc.But I am getting the following error.

> doctrine/mongodb 1.0.3 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.5-dev -> the
>   requested PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.6.6) installed.

My composer.json is as following:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
    "ismaambrosi/generator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "~2.0",
    "bicpi/html-converter-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "^2.6",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "~1.2"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
}
```

I am running this command on command Line:

```
$ composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle @stable
```

I have tried to change `"minimum-stability": "stable"`, into `"dev"` but it is still not working.

What I am missing or what should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: You have imcopatibilities versions in your vendors, have you tried to test : "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "@stable" and "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "@stable" ?

Comment: No, Let me try this as well

Comment: Getting same Error with this as well.

Comment: imcopatibilities versions means?

Comment: My bad, like the error message suggests, you have to downgrade your PHP MongoDB extension. The vendor uses a minor version (version 1.5 max) but you have the 1.6.6 installed.

Comment: But My Whole application running on this version of mongo: it will not create any issue if I will "Downgrade" mongo version.?

Comment: No just downgrade the PHP MongoDB extension not your Mongo version.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to "downgrade the PHP MongoDB extension ". please I need it urgent

Comment: You can try : pecl install mongo-1.4.0 (or any other version below 1.5). Before, make sure your current version is really 1.6.6. [help here](http://serverfault.com/questions/631479/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-a-pecl-package)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117035/discussion-between-sunil-singh-rawat-and-ugo-t).